# Django model query - how to join string list with F expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a model with array field and now a new string field required to hold content from array field with string format.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    array_field = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(
            max_length=255,
            blank=True,
            null=True
        ),
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    text_field = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I intend to use F() with update() like below

```
MyModel.objects.filter(array_field__isnull=False).update(text_field="; ".join(F("array_field")))
```

But it gives me below error

```
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

Does F() work with join()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From django doc(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/):

> An F() object represents the value of a model field, transformed value of a model field, or annotated column. **It makes it possible to refer to model field values and perform database operations using them without actually having to pull them out of the database into Python memory**.

In your case, when you use `"; ".join(F("array_field"))`, `F("array_field")` actually does not take the execution result into python's memory, so you can not use join with it.

Understanding how, why, and when to use `F` will help you understand your problem, Django doc is a good place to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`.join(iterable)` **returns** `TypeError` whenever you call it on **non-iterable** objects as `integers`, `floats`, `None`,.. So make sure `F("array_field")` is **iterable**!

**aslo if the iterable contains any non-string values, it raises a TypeError exception.**